# How Do I send VoIP push notifications to an iOS device using Amazon SNS in Node JS

Tags: ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am trying to send VoIP push notifications directly to an iOS device from an App server using the NodeJS package called [sns-mobile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sns-mobile) and [Amazon SNS API](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/SNS/latest/sns-api.pdf).

However, When I try to send VoIP pushes using the below code, here is the error message that I get. Could someone please suggest me where I am going wrong, I have been spending nearly half a day to resolve this.

> Invalid parameter: JSON must contain an entry for 'default' or
>   'APNS_VOIP

```
var iOSApp = new SNS({
      platform: SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.IOS,
      region: 'us-west-2',
      apiVersion: '2010-03-31',
      accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      platformApplicationArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:3303035XXXXX:app/APNS_VOIP/VoIPPushesApp'
    }); 

iOSApp.addUser('deviceID', 
  JSON.stringify({
   "APNS_VOIP": JSON.stringify({aps:{alert:"Hello and have a good day."}})
  })
  , function(err, endpointArn) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("The Error is :****: "+JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
    throw err;
  }


  // Send a simple String or data to the client 
  iOSApp.sendMessage(endpointArn, 'Hi There!', function(err, messageId) {
  //iOSApp.sendMessage(endpointArn, messageTest, function(err, messageId) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("The Error in end message is :****: "+JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Message sent, ID was: ' + messageId);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that send a VoIP notifications to the receiver device using its device VoIP token. When a VoIP notification is received, the device calls a function called, `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload`

```
var AWS                   =   require('aws-sdk');

// Amazon SNS module
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId     : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  region          : 'us-west-2'
});

var amazonSNS             =   new AWS.SNS();

// 1. Create Platform Endpoint
var createPlatformEndpoint = function(req, res, next){
  var deviceVoipToken = req.deviceVoipToken;  // Obtaining the device VoIP token from the request object

  amazonSNS.createPlatformEndpoint({
    // App in Sandboxmode (ie running on device directly from Xcode)
    PlatformApplicationArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:app/APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX/CurieVoip",
    // App in Production mode (ie running on device after archiving and installed on device with a provisioning profile)
    //PlatformApplicationArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:app/APNS_VOIP/CurieVoip",
    Token: deviceVoipToken


  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
      response.json({"status": "failure", "statusCode" : 402})
      return;
    }
    var endpointArn = data.EndpointArn;
    req.endpointArn = data.EndpointArn; // Passing the EndpointArn to the next function
    next()
  })
}


// 2. Publish notification
var publishVoipNotification = function(req, res, next){
  var endpointArn = req.endpointArn;

  var payload = {
    default   : 'Hello World, default payload',
    APNS_VOIP : {
      aps: {
        alert: 'Hi there',
        sound: 'default',
        badge: 1
      }
    }
  };

  // first have to stringify the inner APNS object...
  payload.APNS = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS);
  // then have to stringify the entire message payload
  payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

  console.log('sending push');
  amazonSNS.publish({
    MessageStructure  : 'json',
    Message           : payload,
    TargetArn         : endpointArn
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error stack: "+err.stack);
      var message =  "There has been an error in Publishing message via AmazonSNS with error: "+err.stack;
      res.json({"status": "failure", "statusCode" : 402, "message" : message})
      return;
    }
    next();
  });
}


// 3. Deleting platform endpoint after sending a voipNotification; Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#deleteEndpoint-property
var deleteEndpointArn = function(req, res){
  var endpointArn = req.endpointArn;
  var roomName    = req.roomName;

  var params = {
    EndpointArn: endpointArn /* required */
  };

  amazonSNS.deleteEndpoint(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
      var message = "Unable to deleteEndpointArn, with error: "+err.stack;
      res.json({"status": "failure", "statusCode" : 400, "message":message})
    }
    else{
      var message = "Deleted endpointArn successfully";
      res.json({"status": "success", "statusCode" : 200, "message":message})

    }
  });
}
router.post('/sendVoipNotificationToReceiver', [createPlatformEndpoint, publishVoipNotification, deleteEndpointArn]);
```

Comment: it's not working in nodejs..? can you explain. how i can integrate in nodejs API..?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Amazon SNS
2. Click on Mobile: Push notifications
3. Click on Create platform Application,
4. User Apple Credentials  "Used for development in sandbox"  check this checkbox if you want to test voip notification on sandbox.
5. Push certificate type -- Voip Push certificate
6. Upload Certificate  .P12 files.
7. Save Form and copy ARN

Create Lambda function. Code example below

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set region
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var amazonSNS = new AWS.SNS();

const isset = (s) => {
    return typeof s !== typeof undefined ? true : false;
};

exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
    let data = event['body-json'];
    if (isset(data)) {
        let getAction = data['action'];
        let userToken = data['token'];
        let webPayload = data['payload'];

        if (isset(getAction) && getAction == 'APNS_VOIP') {
            amazonSNS.createPlatformEndpoint({
                PlatformApplicationArn: 'YOUR APPLICATION ARN',
                Token: userToken
            }, function (err, data1) {
                if (err) {
                    //handle error
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    //Publish notification
                    var endpointArn = data1.EndpointArn;
                    console.log("endpointArn",endpointArn);
                    var payload = {
                        default: 'Silent voip push notification',
                        APNS_VOIP: {
                            //aps:webPayload
                            "aps" : {
                                "alert" : {
                                    "title" : "Call Request"
                                },
                                "data":webPayload,
                                "content-available":1,
                                "category":"GENERAL"
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    payload.APNS_VOIP = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS_VOIP);
                    payload = JSON.stringify(payload);
                    amazonSNS.publish({
                        MessageStructure: 'json',
                        Message: payload,
                        MessageAttributes:{
                            "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PRIORITY":{"DataType":"String","StringValue":"10"}, 
                            "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PUSH_TYPE":{"DataType":"String","StringValue":"voip"} 
                        },
                        TargetArn: endpointArn
                    }, function (err, data2) {
                        if (err) {
                            //handle error
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            var params = {
                                EndpointArn: endpointArn /* required */
                            };
                            //Deleting platform endpoint after sending a voipNotification; 
                            amazonSNS.deleteEndpoint(params, function (err, data3) {
                                if (err) {
                                    //handle error
                                    //console.log(err);
                                    callback(null, {
                                        "status": "error",
                                        "data": [],
                                        "message": []
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    //code success
                                    console.log("delete",data3);
                                    callback(null, {
                                        "status": "Success",
                                        "data": data3,
                                        "message":"notification sent successfully"
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else if (isset(getAction) && getAction == 'APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX') {
            amazonSNS.createPlatformEndpoint({
                PlatformApplicationArn: 'YOUR APPLICATION ARN',
                Token: userToken
            }, function (err, data1) {
                if (err) {
                    //handle error
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    //Publish notification
                    var endpointArn = data1.EndpointArn;
                    console.log("endpointArn",endpointArn);
                    var payload = {
                            default: 'Silent voip push notification',
                            APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX: {
                        "aps" : {
                            "alert" : {
                                "title" : "Call Request"
                            },
                            "data":webPayload,
                            "content-available":1,
                            "category":"GENERAL"
                        }
                    }
                        };
                    payload.APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX);
                    payload = JSON.stringify(payload);
                    amazonSNS.publish({
                        MessageStructure: 'json',
                        Message: payload,
                        MessageAttributes:{
                            "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PRIORITY":{"DataType":"String","StringValue":"10"}, 
                            "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PUSH_TYPE":{"DataType":"String","StringValue":"voip"} 
                        },
                        TargetArn: endpointArn
                    }, function (err, data2) {
                        if (err) {
                            //handle error
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            var params = {
                                EndpointArn: endpointArn /* required */
                            };
                            //Deleting platform endpoint after sending a voipNotification; Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#deleteEndpoint-property
                            amazonSNS.deleteEndpoint(params, function (err, data3) {
                                if (err) {
                                    //handle error
                                    //console.log(err);
                                    callback(null, {
                                        "status": "error",
                                        "data": [],
                                        "message": []
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    //code success
                                    console.log("delete",data3);
                                    callback(null, {
                                        "status": "Success",
                                        "data": data3,
                                        "message":"notification sent successfully"
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            callback(null, {
                "status": "error",
                "data": [],
                "message": "You have not posted valid data."
            });
        }
    }

};
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html

[How Do I send VoIP push notifications to an iOS device using Amazon SNS in Node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307830/how-do-i-send-voip-push-notifications-to-an-ios-device-using-amazon-sns-in-node)